# Python - Doesn't recognize Ascii char value of 2

Tags: python, ascii

The purpose of my code is to remove all text from a file that falls between control-c (ASCII value of 3) and control-b (ASCII value of 2). My code enters the first if statement when it sees a value of 3 but never sees a 2 and it should. The loop just repeats until the end of file is reached. I've heard of python having issues with ASCII but can't figure out why the 2 isn't seen.

Code:

```
i = 1
j=1
while i< size:
    char1 = input[i:i+1]
    num = ord(char1)

    if num == 3:
        for j in range (i,size):
            char2 = input[j:j+1]
            num2 = ord(char2)

            if num == 2:
                print "we found a 2"
        i=j

    else:
        result=char1
        fresult = fresult+result
        i=i+1

print fresult
```

Comment: Please post a complete program.  Your code does not define `size`, `input` nor `fresult`.  Also please post sample input that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: this code only detects ASCII \002 if \003 has been detected first. And also the typo where num is compared and not num2. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

I think this line of code:

```
if num == 2:
```

is supposed to test `num2`, not `num`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a couple of suggestions about your code separate from the error @JohnGordon points out in his answer.

1. Don't call your string `input` - `input` is the name of a built-in function in both Python 2 and Python 3.
2. When you just want the `i`th element of a list, you don't need to use a slice. Instead of `my_list[i:i+1]`, you can just use `my_list[i]`
3. See @John Gordon's answer about `if num == 2` - you are comparing the wrong variable (and that is dead code since num can never simultaneously be both 2 and 3).

Here's the test code I used based on what you already had.

```
test_str = 'abc\x03def\x02ghi'
i = 0
j = 0
size = len(test_str)
result = ''

while i < size:
    char1 = test_str[i]
    num1 = ord(char1)

    if num1 == 3:
        for j in xrange(i, size):
            char2 = test_str[j]
            num2 = ord(char2)

            if num2 == 2:
                print "we found a 2"
                j += 1
                break
        i = j
    else:
        result += char1
        i += 1

print result
```

Which outputs:

```
we found a 2
abcghi
```